# Preselect value in a Dropdown(select) KnockoutJS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I am trying to preselect a value in a Dropdown. I am using KnockoutJS and calling a webservice to push values into my list. However, I am unable to preselect the value I want. Your help is much appreciated. I also did notice that an alert placed in ko.utils.arrayFirst is not being displayed. Thanks!

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/platform/vendors.asmx" />
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/platform/checkBooks.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
</form>
<div>
    <p>
        Checkbooks:
        <select data-bind="options: cb, value: choice, optionsText: 'name'"></select>

    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function errorHandler(errorObject) {
        var errType = errorObject._exceptionType;
        var errMsg = errorObject._message;
        window.alert("ERROR" + errType + ":" + errMsg);
        return false;
    }

    ko.observableArray.fn.find = function (prop, data) {
        var valueToMatch = data[prop];
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(this(), function (item) {
            return (item[prop] === valueToMatch);
        });
    };

    function viewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.cb = new ko.observableArray([]);

        self.call = function () {
            try {
                checkBooks.list("accounting", 2, "name:", self.retCheckBooks, errorHandler);
            }
            catch (ex) {
                alert(ex.message);
            }
        }
        self.retCheckBooks = function (results) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= results.length; i++) {
                self.cb.push({ id: i, name: results[i].shortName });
            }
        }
        var choice = { id: 4, name: "VCSTPAY" };
        self.choice = ko.observable(self.cb.find("id", choice));
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        vm = new viewModel();
        vm.call();
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Could you paste a sample of the output of the asmx files? Without it, I just get `checkBooks is undefined`.

Comment: Hi,
The webservice is a pretty large file and I am referring a couple other cs files inside of it. It will be confusing and extremely large if i try to put all that here. I will see if i can fork out a better example with a simpler webservice. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I don't mean the code. I just want something to put in `checkBooks` to test your JavaScript.

Comment: results[i].shortName displays the names of the checkbooks. For this example, we could have cb1, cb2, cb3, VCSTPAY, cb5. And i would like 4th one in the list to be pre-selected.

Answer (score 1):

Add `optionsValue: "id"` to your data-binding and change choice to:

```
self.choice = ko.observable(choice.id);
```

By default, KO does not know how to compare your choice objects to match `value` to one of the `options`.

Comment: Why would you add the additional complexity instead of just passing in an object directly from the array such as self.choice = ko.observable(cb()[0]); ?